# Is it possible to "appendListItem" starting from a specific number?

Tags: google-apps-script

Of course you can append a "numbered" list item, then it starts from 1 and counts from there automaticly.

I'd like my script to append a numbered list item, but not starting from 1 but instead from an arbitrary number.

Is that even possible in Google Apps Script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with GAS.

The closest you can get is to continue the numbering of a list even if the list items are not consecutive in the document. To do that, get the list id of the previous list item using `.getListId()` on an existing item and then `.setListId(id)` on the new item you are appending.

Comment: thank you, what i was looking for was to continue an ordered number list between different documents, which i guess isn't possible.

Comment: It isn't. Also in the answer above, the setListID doesn't work like that, sadly. You can only set it to be the same as an existing listitem:
item2.setListId( item1)

Answer (score 0):

You can insert a list item using the `insertListItem()` method:

[Google Documentation - insertListItem](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#insertListItem(Integer,ListItem))

```
var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();

// Append a new list item to the body.
var item1 = body.insertListItem(childIndex, listItem);

// Log the new list item's list ID.
Logger.log(item1.getListId());
```